# How to make the RedirectToPage work When Using Areas

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, routes, razor-pages, .net-6.0

I am working on a .NET 6 Web app for testing, and run into problem with RedirectToPage in a Razor page when using Areas.  Here are the details.

**TEST ENVIRONMENT**

ASP.NET framework:  .NET 6
App pattern: Razor pages (without MVC)
Authentication:  with simple cookies
IDE:  Visual Studio 2022
Developer machine: Windows 11

**PROJECT STRUCTURE**

```
MyProject
    Areas
        |----Public
                |----Pages
                ......
                
        |----Internal
                |----Pages
                        |---- Index.cshtml
                        |---- Authenticate
                                |---- UserLogin.cshtml
                                      UserLogin.cs
                        |---- Products
                        |---- Services
                           
    Pages
        |---- Shared
        |---- Index.cshtml
        |---- Error.cshtml
```

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION**

After a user provides the credential at the UserLogin.cshtml page, the "OnPost" method in UserLogin.cs class handles the verification. If the login is successful, it should redirect the user to the Index.cshtml page in the root of Internal area (see the code segment below).

I have tried different ways to specify the page name in RedirectToPage statement. But, none of them worked.  (Note: Using browser, I can access the index page using url"http://localhost:12345/Internal/Index")

```
"Index"
"/Index"
"./Index"
"/Internal/Index" (without using 2nd input param)
"./Internal/Index" (without using 2nd input param)
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
{
    // verify user ID and password against DB
    bool IsVerified = CheckUserLogin(LoginUser.UserId, LoginUser.Password);

    if (IsVerified)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim("username", LoginUser.UserId));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, LoginUser.UserId));

        // test statement for using name property in claim
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, LoginUser.FullName));

        //test statements for using user role property in clain
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin,research"));

        var claimIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        var claimPrinciple = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimIdentity);
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimPrinciple);

        return RedirectToPage("Index", new { area = "Internal" });
    }
    return Page();
}
```

**QUESTION**
What is the correct way of specifying the "route" in RedirectToPage statement for a razor page under an Area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your structure,I suggest  you with two options:

Option1: If you use Razor View,  try `return RedirectToPage("../Index");`

Option2: If you use Razor Page, try `return RedirectToPage("/Index", new { area = "Internal" });`